# Error when opening images uploaded from angular to rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angular, filereader

I'm trying to upload files from angular 5 application to ruby on rails app.
The upload is working well for files of type text, csv but when i try to upload an image type png or jpg the file is uploaded but can not be opened.

- **Ruby on rails**

  ```
  File.open('./tmp/source/'+params['doc']['filename'],'w') do |file| 
  file.puts Base64.decode64(params['doc']['value']).force_encoding("utf-8")
  ```

  end
- **Angular**

  ```
  loadImg(event){
  if (event.target.files && event.target.files[0]) {
    var reader = new FileReader();

    reader.onload = (event: ProgressEvent) => {
      this.user.image = (<FileReader>event.target).result;
      this.user_image['value'] = (<FileReader>event.target).result;
    }
    reader.readAsDataURL(event.target.files[0]);
    this.user_image['filename'] = event.target.files[0].name;
   }
  }
  ```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Files of type jpg png are uploaded but can not be opened using an image viewer. There is an error with the file encoding. How to fix it ?